# several digits validation in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am going to implement the validation in angular 4.

I've already have a solution but need simple and clean code.

Here is my code.

- mobile-auth.component.ts

  ```
  this.appForm = fb.group({
       'otp': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidationService.digit4Validator])],
  });
  ```
- validation.service.ts

  ```
  ...
  static digit4Validator(control) {
      if (control.value) {
         if (control.value.match(/^\d+/) && control.value.length === 4) {
             return null;
         } else {
             return {'invalid4DigitCode': true};
         }
      }
  }
  ...
  ```

If you have any good solution please let me know.

Comment: So you already have a solution you just want to know if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Yeah. As you can see, I've already implemented the validation but wanna more clean and professional one.

Answer (score 0):

Your validator should only validate that it's a valid number. Angular already provides a minlength validator which should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your validator as this:

```
export function digitValidator(length: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    if (control.value) {
       if (control.value.match(/^\d+/) && control.value.length === length) {
           return null;
       } else {
           return {`invalidDigitCode, length should be ${length}`: true};
       }
    }
  };
}
...
this.appForm = fb.group({
     'otp': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
                 Validators.digitValidator(4)])
...
```

Or you can use like this:

```
this.appForm = fb.group({
     'otp': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
                 Validators.minLength(4), 
                 Validators.maxLength(4)])],
});
```